# Wordpress change the order of posts through the standard loop

Tags: php, wordpress

is it possible to order posts while keeping the standard Wordpress loop intact (i.e. without having to create a whole new WP_Query?

By standard loop I mean:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>


            <?php /* The loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Can I specify the order within this code?

Answer (score 8):

As [documented](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) at `query_posts` function page:

> It is ***strongly*** recommended that you use the `pre_get_posts` filter
>   instead, and alter the main query by checking `is_main_query`.

You can add a new action on `pre_get_posts` in your theme `functions.php` file, like:

```
function homepage_posts($query)
{
    if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query())
    {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'homepage_posts');
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding the following to my functions.php file but it had no effect. I am trying to get the order of a custom post type to be random on the category.php page:
`function cat_posts($query)
{
    if ($query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query())
    {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'cat_posts');`

Comment: @Kev you should change your `if` condition to `if($query->is_category)`

Answer (score 1):

[wp_reset_query()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_query/) is the way to go

**Example snippet**

```
<?php query_posts(array('orderby'=>'title','order'=>'DESC'));

if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a><br /><?php
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

But keep in mind: query_posts() will change your main query and is not recommended. Only use if absolutely necessary (see query_posts: Caveats). Creating a new instance of WP_Query or get_posts() is preferred for secondary loops.

Comment: Thank you, I gave this a go but got the following error: `syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW`